# Можно ли добавить разделитель между элементами OptionsMenu?(V1.1)

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! Я задавал этот же вопрос 2 дня назад, но ответа конкретного не получил.
цитирую предыдущий вопрос:

> Задался вопросом, а можно ли добавить
>   горизонтальную или вертикальную линию
>   между элементами `OptionsMenu`? Мне
>   кажется, что нельзя, да и решения я не
>   нашел вообще, однако решил уточнить.
>   Вот пример как должно быть, т.е. между
>   пунктами меню есть и вертикальные и
>   горизонтальные разделители(они
>   стандартные, на эмуляторе есть), а на
>   устройсве, куда я ставлю прогу, там
>   нет таких, просто отображается текст,
>   без линий. Подскажите как это
>   реализовать принудительно?

И да, если можно, то при каждом нажатии на кнопку menu, элементы должны обновляться(это сейчас работает, но вот если добавить разделители это тоже должно остаться), потому что несут в себе информацию, которая меняется довольно часто.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конкретный ответ получил: сделать кастомное меню.
Создаешь:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    addOptionsMenuHackerInflaterFactory();
    return true;
}
```

Клики по пунктам меню:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    }
}
```

`addOptionsMenuHackerInflaterFactory()` -- хак для версий 2.3 и выше, чтобы на всех версиях отображалось одинаково. Почитать подробнее [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944244/change-the-background-color-of-the-options-menu/8475357#8475357). В нем есть строчка `v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)`, меняешь на `v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button)`, делаешь свой рисунок с нужными линиями.     Это извращенный, но рабочий метод, возможно есть проще.